# JavaScript Calculate expression in octal radix

Tags: javascript, radix

For example, I have the following string:

```
15+6
```

I want to calculate this expression in octal radix. So I want to get:

```
23
```

Is there any function in js to support this case? If not, what is the best approach to calculate octal expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with radix 8 and convert it to octal with [`Number#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) again with radix.

Please have a look here: [Numbers and dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates). The use of octal numbers is dependent of strict mode.

```js
document.write((parseInt(15, 8) + parseInt(6, 8)).toString(8) + '<br>');
```

Comment: why do we need to convert it as a string? I am so confused, why `parseInt(15, 8) + parseInt(6, 8)` is displaying `19`

Comment: Ok, in `ES6` it's just slightly another syntax `0o15 + 0o6 == 19 && 0o15 + 0o6 == 0o23`

Answer (score 1):

Using `ES6` standard:

> In ECMAScript 6 Octal number is supported with by prefixing a number with "0o".

```js
var result = 0o15 + 0o6;
document.write(result.toString(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce if there are many calculations to be done, or @Nina's answer...

```
var str = '15+6';
var res = str.split('+').reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + parseInt(b, 8)
}, 0).toString(8)
console.log(res) // 23
```

Comment: What if there is not only "+" operator in the expression?
Of cause we can use regex /\+|\-/, but how we can define current operation while calculating.
Also, I hope there is more elegant way to calculate expressions (without splitting)